# Laravel cant detect env when generating an key

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to generate an application key, what I got is

`Unable to set application key. No APP_KEY variable was found in the .env file.`

even if I have an `.env` file on my server directory

```
root@..:/var/www/html# ls -la
total 556
drwxrwxrwt 14 www-data www-data   4096 Sep  1 14:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       4096 Aug 16 02:12 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    258 Sep  1 14:47 .editorconfig
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   1972 Sep  1 14:51 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data    821 Sep  1 14:47 .env.example
```

my env

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:****************************
APP_DEBUG=true
```

I am using docker btw.

Comment: can you show your `compose.yml` to check the volumes of services? try set the env [by](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#use-the-env_file-attribute) this.

Comment: please include compose.yml

Comment: Might be helpful: [Unable to set application key...](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/unable-to-set-application-key-no-app-key-variable-was-found-in-the-env-file)